# Find output of MySQL inbuilt function in CLI using custom parameter

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I want to see the working of MySQL functions `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` by providing the parameters to them myself in CLI, something like this:
    `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1459460268);`
without having to insert these custom values in a table first and then selecting them to see the output.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function accepts a `date` and you are giving it UNIX TIMESTAMP. You can simply run this in MySQL CLI and get the results:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2016-04-01 03:07:48");

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1459460268);

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

The last one will return you the current UNIX TIMESTAMP.

Happy coding!